# Parsing SOAP with xpaths

Tags: java, xpath, soap

Using regular HTML given something like this:

```html
<DIV>
  <DIV>
   Tony
  </DIV>
  <DIV>
   52
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

I can find the xpath of my name using below xpath:-

```
//div[contains(text(),'Tony')]/../div[2]
```

But how do you do this with a soap xpath?  We have a class called Method and when you execute you say (Method m) m.execute() and then `m.getElementText(xpath,substitutions)` where *substitions* has the replacements for the element (e.g. ns5).  I think these were custom made but the question still applies to xpaths.

I know only how to use static xpaths like  `*//{0}:Person/{0}:Age.*`  I am wondering how I can specify something like `*//{0}:contains(@{0}:name,'Tony')/..//{0}:Age*`
(that is search for an element with a specific value).

This would be something like

```html
<ns5:person>
  <ns5:name>Tony</ns5:name>
  <ns5:Age>52</ns5:Age>
</ns5:person>>
```

How could I do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given that the expression `//{0}:Person/{0}:Age` worked, I think embedding `contains()` in predicate like the following will also work :

```
//{0}:Person[contains({0}:name,'Tony')]/{0}:Age
```

Comment: Is this also possible?  Use an and?  This would be just to find the Person element:

//{0}:Person[contains({0}:name,'Tony') AND contains({0}:age,'52')]?  I guess I can try it